# How to handle user equal nil when it is not detected by ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jwt

I am learning programming only, Ruby on Rails in particular. The problem I face currently is that I doubt in which way to handle my issue is better regarding clean code and avoiding my code smells or probably something else.

So basically, I have users_controller where I check if my `jwt` is valid: I decode it, withdraw `user_id` and look for the user in DB by her `id`.

```
 def login
    user = decoded_user(permitted_params[:jwt])
    render json: user
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, JWT::DecodeError
    render status: 401, json: { error: 'invalid token' }.to_json
  end
```

As you can see, in case of invalid jwt or user is not found, it must render `401 error`, but somehow when user is `nil`, `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` does not detect it and render `200 status` when I want it `401`. When `jwt` is valid or empty, it all works fine.

I was thinking to wrap it into `if else` block in case of `nil` though to me it does not seem really skilled. Could you help me to refactor, please? Thanks!

Comment: What is `decoded_user`? Why not just raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` from there?

Comment: @engineersmnky 
`def decoded_user(jwt)
        User.find_by(public_id: decode_user_jwt(jwt)) if decode_user_jwt(jwt)
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        render status: 401, json: { error: 'invalid token' }.to_json
      end`
where 
`decode_user_jwt(jwt)` returns user's id.
I've tried but it doesnt work either

Comment: `find_by` will return `nil` if it cannot find anything, not raise an error. You should correct this code to raise if `nil`. as an aside if `decode_user_jwt(jwt)` returns `false` or `nil` this method will also return `nil` due to the inline conditional

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways how you can handle this with minimal changes.

### find_by!

The first is to make sure an exception is raised when the user is not found. You have used `find_by`, for which the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) says:

> If no record is found, returns `nil`.

For a lot of finder methods in Rails, there are variants with a `!` at the end. The `!` indicates in the context of Rails that the method will raise an exception. For `find_by`, the same `find_by!` variant exists. The [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by-21) for this method tells you that it is exactly like `find_by`, except that it will not return `nil`, but raise an exception.

Replace `find_by` in `decode_user` with `find_by!`, and your method should work as expected.

### Avoid exceptions

Raising exceptions is often seen as an anti pattern. There are many different reasons for this, but one argument often used is that [exceptions are slow](https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby#beginrescue-vs-respond_to-for-control-flow-code). If you look at the code that Rails generated when you use scaffolding, you'll see that controller actions typically look like this:

```
def create
  @test = Test.new(test_params)

  if @test.save
    redirect_to @test, notice: 'Test was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

You can use the same pattern for your method as well. First, decode the user. Then check if the user is exists, e.g. with `user.present?`. Based on that, either return success or failure.

You'll see this pattern a lot in Rails, and I would recommend to refactor your code to follow it here as well...

Comment: thanks a lot :) in my case its API , so i send requests from client made on react, not sure if i can apply redirect_to, at least on client i parse json :)

Comment: That was just an example. In your case, you would not have `redirect_to`, but two `render` statements. The important thing to note is the pattern, where you first fetch a resource, then perform an action on it (`@test.save`), and based on that action's result, return or show something to the user.

Answer (score 0):

As **@engineersmnky** pointed out in the comments, `find_by` **doesn't raise an exception**. It just returns **nil** when there is no record. You should use `find_by!` instead. Your code should look like below

```
def decoded_user(jwt)
  begin 
    User.find_by!(public_id: decode_user_jwt(jwt)) 
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, JWT::DecodeError
  end
end
```

And the `login` method can be changed to just

```
def login
  user = decoded_user(permitted_params[:jwt])
  if user
    render json: user
  else
    render json: {status: 401, error: 'invalid token' }
  end
end
```

Comment: `find` doesn't take keyword arguments, it only works with ids. To raise an exception, use `find_by!` instead.

Comment: @jdno Thanks for the response. I've missed the important part!

Comment: @jdno Updated my answer :)

Comment: You're welcome. It happens to me every so often that I try to pass a keyword to `find`, and then wonder why it doesn't work as excepted. 

Comment: @jdno Welcome to the club :D

Comment: @Pavan thanks a lot! Rails doesnt want rendering in two places, so i moved it to one method instead of both action and method, now all works fine thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Anastasia Alright, will update the answer as well :)